# Custom Calendar View in IOS

Tags: ios, calendar

I want to make custom calendar view in iOS.I can swipe the calendar monthly or weekly.There will be an option for selecting any date.Can anyone give me a link of any tutorial or open source library by which I can customize my own custom calendar view

Comment: ,how to add weekly view or day view to Kal?

Comment: This is by far one the better libraries off-the-shelf: https://github.com/jumartin/Calendar/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try customizing [Tapku](http://tapku.com/). I've tried it a few months ago and I totally didn't like it. The dates were kinda messed up(had 31st of November there). Then I found out [Kal](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal) and I did like it.

Both of them are good to start with I think.

Hope it helps

Comment: I added Kal into my project.Now I want to modify the view of Kal. Is it possible any kind of customization of that view of Kal.Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: @ARC I do believe that Kal is fully customizable. It is only .h and .m files, so if you spend a little while understanding these you should be able to do whatever you need.

Comment: Ok.Thanks I am trying to customize the view.

Answer (score 8):

I made a clean calendar, maybe it could be of use as well
https://github.com/TjeerdVurig/Vurig-Calendar

Comment: Is there any video-demo or just screenshots of your calendar?

Comment: I have downloaded code from the above link .when I select particular date it gives me previous Date instead of Selected date. For example if I select 8th Feb it prints 7th Feb. Any solution wud be great help.

Comment: The dates are in GTM. You can convert them to the local timezone and the selected date will be correct.

-(void)calendarView:(VRGCalendarView *)calendarView dateSelected:(NSDate *)date {
    
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM"];

    NSLog(@"Selected date = %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
}

Comment: is there any way to add events to your calendar sir

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Tapku](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary) and customize the TKCalendarMonthView

Comment: Link takes you to bogus site

Comment: i changed the link and now its working

Answer (score 0):

Its 2016. The others on this page seems outdated and not well maintained. You can find the most flexible one i've ever found here on [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/JTAppleCalendar). With this one i don't think you'll try another.

Comment: While it is very flexible and the author seems convinced of the certain philosophy there (namely, that the framework should not make choices for developers) it is far from being an easy off-the-shelf solution, the kinds of which one may be accustomed to on the web, for example.