# Custom calender with add event in ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

`How to create our own calendar in ipad` , Is there any API ? please suggest me.

I'm searching lots of in google but not any API that create custom calendar and add event in calendar...

Thank You.

Comment: check this link https://github.com/TjeerdVurig/Vurig-Calendar

Comment: in this demo you get simple calendar demo.

Comment: yes, but i required ipad inbuilt calendar format

Comment: sorry but i have only this link and you simply change that calendar size in vrgviewcontroller .

Answer (score 0):

For creating/ managing Calendar Events have a look at `EKEventStore`.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html

You can ofcourse, create your own calendar, but for that you need to play with dates and have to draw the calendar youself.
You may use this open source Calendar, if you dont want to draw everything yorself:

```
klazuka_Calendar 

https://github.com/klazuka/Kal
```

Comment: I like to create calendar like inbuit ipad calendar

Comment: Thats a whole application. You can ofcourse try to build it, but you have to do it from scratch.

Comment: yes, but any api is there that showing the calendar view like inbuilt ipad then add event itegration is easy for creating..

Comment: I needed the same functionality from a Calendar in an app sometimes back. I was not able to find anything that resembles the Calendar app in iOS with its event management functionality. I ended up creating a custom calendar of my own. Cant share the code with you though.

Comment: If not share your code than share some guide lines or any suggestion to create the custom calendar in ipad

Comment: I would sugget you look at the open source Calendar mentioned above in the answer.If you like the look and feel of the Calendar you can modify it to show EKEvents. If you dont like the Calendar then you need to dig into world of NSCalendars and NSDates to create a calendar. You may have to use Core Graphics to draw the Calendar. There are many possibilitiea. For iOS6 and above you can also use UICollectionView. All the best!!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of Resources over the Custom Calendar creation :

Have U gone through these links :

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496880/build-a-custom-calendar-in-ios-app)

[Link 2](http://maniacdev.com/2011/09/open-source-customizable-ios-calendar-component-with-landscape-orientation-support)

[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579080/custom-calendar-view-in-ios)

If you do with the Ios Calender then just go through the: `EKEventstore`

[EventKitProgramGuide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Yes but not any api that showing the event like inbuilt ipad calendar.. its only showing the calendar date

Comment: That depends on your creation . You can't simply import the IOS Calender into the app.